# Как циклом for заполнить пустой массив?

Tags: javascript, for

Вот условие: "в первый элемент запишите 'x', во второй 'xx', в третий 'xxx' и так далее."

Вот до чего я додумался и остановился:

```js
let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let x = 'x'
  arr[i].push()   
}
```

Comment: `Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_,i) => 'x'.repeat(i + 1))`

Comment: @entithat, у тебя нет цикла for :)

Comment: @Grundy, Я ж по этому и в комментарии оставил :) Еще один хороший пример показал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr.push( 'x'.repeat(i+1) ) ;
}

console.log(arr);
```

```js
let arr = []
let x = 'x';
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr.push(x) ;
    x += 'x';
}

console.log(arr);
```

последнее, впрочем, можно сократить до

```js
let arr = []
for (let  x = 'x'; x.length <= 10; x +='x') arr.push(x) ;    


console.log(arr);
```